# Querying firestore to check if field value exist and Converting Stream into Future?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function which i created to query firestore and checkwhether a phoneNo exist in the collection called 'users'

I want to get a boolean if the phone No already exist in a document field.
How can i do it

```
Future<bool> phoneRegisterCheck(phone) async{
    bool phoneAlreadyRegistered;
    print('start');
    var result = Firebase.instance.collection('users').where('phoneNo', isEqualTo: phone);
}
```

I want to wait for the query to finish and then return the result.
When i Use listen method it is not happening right function returns null.

```
Future<bool> phoneRegisterCheck(phone) async{
    bool phoneRegistered;
    print('start');
    var result = DatabaseService().userCollection.where('phoneNo', isEqualTo: phone);
    result.snapshots().listen((val){
      val.documents.isEmpty ? phoneRegistered=false:phoneRegistered=true;
    });
    return phoneRegistered;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `streams` are asynchronous then in your code the return statement will be executed before the data is fully retrieved therefore you get null. You should
use `await for` instead of `listen`:

```
Future<bool> phoneRegisterCheck(phone) async{
    bool phoneRegistered;
    print('start');
    var result = DatabaseService().userCollection.where('phoneNo', isEqualTo: phone).snapshots();
    await for(var values in result){
      values.documents.isEmpty ? phoneRegistered=false:phoneRegistered=true;
    }
    return phoneRegistered;
  }
```

From the docs:

> Streams can be created in many ways, which is a topic for another article, but they can all be used in the same way: the asynchronous for loop (commonly just called await for) iterates over the events of a stream like the for loop iterates over an Iterable.

https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams